# WCF service hosted in Sharepoint in Claims mode

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, claims

I have a sharepoint server configured for Https in Claims mode. I have hosted a WCF Service in the sharepoint server. This WCF server uses client certificate for authentication.

The WCF service uses `BasicHttpBinding`.

On the client side following is the binding:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.StreamedResponse;
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.Ntlm;
```

I have also set the client certificate using the following call:

```
base.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
    "CN=tempClientcert", StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My
);
```

The client certificate is correctly setup in the client and the server.

When I try to invoke the service, I get the following error:

```
System.Security.MessageSecurityException :  The HTTP request is unauthorized 
    with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header
    received from the server was 'NTLM'
```

Though i have set the client credential to Certificate, it is unclear as to why it is saying http client authentication scheme is Anonymous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this configuration may have some relevance? [SharePoint, WCF and Anonymous Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847414/sharepoint-wcf-and-anonymous-access) (note mode - TransportOnly)

Answer (score 0):

WCF services support many transport options, they are not fully integrated into SharePoint